# Mouse wheel issues on Pop!_OS

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, scrolling

I'm giving [Pop!_OS](https://system76.com/pop) (based on Ubuntu 19.04) a try, and am experiencing a very annoying issue with the mouse wheel (a Logitech MX Anywhere 2).

First of all the scrolling speed is *very* slow; I read somewhere about the Solaar app for Logitech mice, that would allow me to configure some mouse settings, including scroll wheel speed. Unfortunately, I cannot see any settings in the app:

[image: Solaar]

After some more googling, I found about `imwheel`. I installed it, changed some values in `~/.imwheelrc`, and got a mouse wheel speed closer to what I had on Windows. I can't say it's as smooth, but it's usable. However I'm not that happy with this solution, as this utility does not seem to be installed as a service, and needs to be started manually. So much for the user experience (I was expecting something in Pop!_OS settings).

**Now the very annoying part:** when I start spinning the mouse wheel in Firefox or Chrome, very often the first spin is just ignored, and the scrolling starts the second or third time I hit the wheel. This makes the mouse wheel pretty much unusable for me, and forces me to use the scrollbar to get a consistent scrolling.

**Is there a solution to this problem?**

Answer (score 2):

Believe it or not but changing my batteries of the mouse fixed stuttering / slow mouse wheel. Although everything else worked perfect with the older batteries, the scroll wheel was not working reliable... I should have checked the batteries before changing code /settings within the os... o well, lesson learned. The solution might be less complex than expected ;-)

Comment: The fact that scrolling was perfectly fine in Windows but abysmal elsewhere else confused me. Since scrolling in Windows seemed fine I had assumed it was something else even though I knew my mouse battery was low.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `imwheel` to run on startup in your desktop environment settings. On GNOME you should probably make a `.desktop` file (follow the instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8290652/5495101 and use the `imwheel` command in the `Exec=` field).

For the first scroll spin ignored, I had the same problem on Arch Linux, and fixed it by installing `xf86-input-evdev` (on Ubuntu based distros the package name should be `xserver-xorg-input-evdev`) and rebooting.